# Cordova and Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova-3

I'm working on a very simple app that uses Jquery Mobile and Cordova.js and I'm using the phonegap emulator to run de app on my iPhone connecting it to the phonegap v0.1.9. In the index file I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=yes" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="http://servicios.usig.buenosaires.gov.ar/usig-js/2.4/usig.MapaInteractivo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <script>

            var deviceReadyDeferred = $.Deferred();
            var jqmReadyDeferred    = $.Deferred();

            $(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
                alert("mobile init");
                jqmReadyDeferred.resolve();
            });
            function init() {

                document.addEventListener("deviceReady", deviceReady, false);
                function deviceReady() {
                    alert("device Ready");
                    deviceReadyDeferred.resolve();
                }

                $.when(deviceReadyDeferred,jqmReadyDeferred).then(onDeviceReady);
            }
            function onDeviceReady() {
                // Now safe to use the Cordova API
                alert("End of init");
                app.initialize();
            }

        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
        <title>My app</title>
    </head>
<body onload="init()">
    <div data-role="page">
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not really sure if the way I'm calling the .js files is correct, but it's the way I got it to work more or less. 
Using a Chrome pluging I'm able to emulate my phone and everything works in the order expected. But when I run the app uning phonegap emulator on my phone to run the app, it loads Jquery and I have to minimize and then restore de app to get the deviceready call fired.
Am I calling the functions in the wrong way? or it's a phonegap emulator issue? 
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to type the way I got this to work:

Call to JQuery.js and Cordova.js:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

I got my own index.js file with functions I want to have implemented separately:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script>

        var deviceReadyDeferred = $.Deferred();
        var jqmReadyDeferred = $.Deferred();
       document.addEventListener("deviceReady", deviceReady, false);
        function deviceReady() {

            deviceReadyDeferred.resolve();
        }

        $(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
            jqmReadyDeferred.resolve();
        });
        $.when(deviceReadyDeferred, jqmReadyDeferred).then(doWhenBothFrameworksLoaded);
        function doWhenBothFrameworksLoaded() {
            app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
            Call my own functions from index.js file
        }

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
    <title>Tittle</title>
</head>
<body>... </body>
```

I hope this helps someone else going through the same issues I had. Cheers!